# Text between two tags

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, html

I want to retrieve whatever is between these two tags – `<tr> </tr>` – from an html doc. 
Now I don't have any specific html requirements that would warrant for an html parser. I just plain need something that matches `<tr>` and `</tr>` and gets everything in between and there could be multiple `tr`s. 
I tried awk, which works, but for some reason it ends up giving me duplicates of each row extracted.

```
awk '
/<TR/{p=1; s=$0}
p && /<\/TR>/{print $0 FS s; s=""; p=0}
p' htmlfile> newfile
```

How to go about this?

Comment: IIUC your awk script should be: `'/<tr/{p=1}; p; /<\/tr>/{p=0}'`. Post some example input and expected output if it doesn't work.

Comment: since your `awk` is working but giving duplicates try to pass your awk's output from `sort -u` to get them distinct

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you only want `...` of all `<tr>...</tr>` do:

`grep -o '<tr>.*</tr>' HTMLFILE | sed 's/\(<tr>\|<\/tr>\)//g' > NEWFILE`

For multiline do:

`tr "\n" "|" < HTMLFILE | grep -o '<tr>.*</tr>' | sed 's/\(<tr>\|<\/tr>\)//g;s/|/\n/g' > NEWFILE`

Check the HTMLFILE first of the char "|" (not usual, but possible) and if it exists, change to one which doesn't exist.

Comment: That'll only work if the start and end tags are on the same line.

Comment: `echo "bla<tr>foo</tr>bla<tr>bar</tr>bla" | grep -o '<tr>.*</tr>' | sed 's/\(<tr>\|<\/tr>\)//g'` gives `fooblabar`. The `bla` should not be there?

Comment: @l0b0 correct. will go for a multiline-compatible one...

Comment: `grep -Po '<tr>.*?</tr>'` would return one result per line in @N.N.'s case, but it's not portable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'specs' or 'spec-style' but note that *your web browser uses an html parser* and an html parser will parse html regardless of how it is written.  It will not parse things that are not html, but then, neither will your browser, so no one would bother writing "html" that a parser cannot parse. In other words: A decent parser is *absolutely certainly* your best bet for doing this.

Comment: xx4h, heck it does the job! thanks for the -o option. I went with this `cat $htmlfile | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/\(<tr>\)/\n\1/gI' | sed 's/\(<\/tr>\)/\1\n/gI' | grep -o '<TR.*</TR>' > newfile`

Comment: It simply does not work well. Please test it a bit more.

Answer (score 12):

[You do have a requirement that warrants an HTML parser: you need to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Perl's [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder), Python's [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and others are easy to use, easier than writing complex and brittle regular expressions.

```
perl -MHTML::TreeBuilder -le '
    $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($ARGV[0]) or die $!;
    foreach ($html->look_down(_tag => "tr")) {
        print map {$_->as_HTML()} $_->content_list();
    }
' input.html
```

or

```
python -c 'if True:
    import sys, BeautifulSoup
    html = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1]).read())
    for tr in html.findAll("tr"):
        print "".join(tr.contents)
' input.html
```

Answer (score 9):

`sed` and `awk` are not well suited for this task, you should rather use a proper html parser. For example `hxselect` from w3.org:

```
<htmlfile hxselect -s '\n' -c 'tr'
```

Comment: I dunno if hxselect is the best choice; I haven't used it *but* the man page does say it "reads a well-formed XML document" which many html documents are not.  Probably worth a try tho.  The html parser libs available for perl, python, et. al. will be much better, if that is an option.

Comment: @goldilocks: Best choice depends on the situation. In my experience `hxselect` does pretty good job with well-formed html/xml documents. Also, it's faster to use than perl, python and others. I think `hxselect` is a good middle-ground between `sed`/`awk` and parser libs.

Comment: If it works that's great! I was just adding a caveat for TechJack in case it didn't -- since I had also recommended using some kind of parser ;)  The programming lib ones are of course more awkward but should deal with anything remotely passable as html.

Comment: Thor, `hxselect` looks good, will definitely explore it more. Thanks.

Comment: @goldilocks: `hxnormalize` takes care of non well-formed html/xml files.

Answer (score 5):

If `ruby` is available you can do the following

```ruby
ruby -e 'puts readlines.join[/(?<=<tr>).+(?=<\/tr>)/m].gsub(/<\/?tr>/, "")' file
```

where `file` is your input html file. The command executes a Ruby one-liner. First, it reads all lines from `file` and joins them to a string, `readlines.join`. Then, from the string it selects anything between (but not including) `<tr>` and `<\/tr>` that is one character or longer irrespective of newlines, `[/(?<=<tr>).+(?=<\/tr>)/m]`. Then, it removes any `<tr>` or `</tr>` from the string, `gsub(/<\/?tr>/, "")` (this is necessary to handle nested `tr` tags). Finally, it prints the string, `puts`.

You said that a html parser is not warranted for you but it is very easy to use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) with `ruby` and it makes the command simpler.

```ruby
ruby -rnokogiri -e 'puts Nokogiri::HTML(readlines.join).xpath("//tr").map { |e| e.content }' file
```

`-rnokogiri` loads Nokogiri. `Nokogiri::HTML(readlines.join)` reads all lines of `file`. `xpath("//tr")` picks out every `tr` element and `map { |e| e.content }` picks out the content for each element, i.e. what is between `<tr>` and `</tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

#### `grep`

To retrieve content within `tr` tag across multiple lines, pass it through `xargs` first, for example:

```
curl -sL https://www.iana.org/ | xargs | egrep -o "<tr>.*?</tr>"
```

To return only inner HTML, use:

```
curl -sL https://www.iana.org/ | xargs | grep -Po "<tr>\K(.*?)</tr>" | sed "s/..tr.//g"
```

<sup>Check the syntax for [`perlre` extended patterns](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).</sup>

<sup>Note: For quicker performance, you may consider [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which has similar syntax.</sup>

Comment: it printed out nicer looking without the xargs, came in handy to find inline javascript using egrep -o "<script .*?</script>"

Answer (score 1):

#### [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup)

Example using [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) (which uses [CSS selectors](https://github.com/ericchiang/css)):

```
pup -f myfile.html tr
```

To print only text without tags, use: `pup -f myfile.html tr text{}`.

Here are few examples with `curl`:

```
curl -sL https://www.iana.org/ | pup tr text{}
pup -f <(curl -sL https://www.iana.org/) tr text{}
```

#### [`xpup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup)

Example using [`xpup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) for HTML/XML parsing (which supports XPath):

```
xpup -f myfile.html "//tr"
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is just a quick listing of `<tr>`s this could help:

```
perl -ne 'print if /<tr>/../</tr>/' your.html > TRs.log
```

cheers

Comment: Have you tried it?