# How to parse XML to CSV with a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, xml

What is the ideal way to parse an `.xml` file into a `.csv` file that I could include with my shell scripts.  I know bash can't do it but I'm unsure if I should try in `awk` or `sed`.  I imagine a language would be the best solution such as python but I do not know python nor have I touched it.

Comment: As [has been argued before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64747/8677) parsing tag structured files warrants a real parser. You could e.g. use Ruby and use [Nokigiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse XML and [the class CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to output CSV. Also, please add a simple example of input and output so that it understandable what you expect from an answer.

Comment: The answer to this question depends partly on the actual document. There is no sample in the question, so it's difficult to give specific answers.

Comment: Why would spend time on a question that is almost a decade old and doesn't show any other activity till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Xmlstarlet (AKA `xml`) as a XSLT transformer and write a specific CSV transform as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/952389/1481060