# Confused about how to convert XML to CSV using xmlstarlet on OS X?

Tags: osx, csv, xml

I asked a question earlier and it was closed as being a duplicate: [How to parse XML to CSV with a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65648/how-to-parse-xml-to-csv-with-a-shell-script). The answer in the duplicate that was linked suggested using a tool called XMLStarlet, but I'm unsure how to use this tool on OS X.

Additionally, there was a link to another Q&A titled: "[Text between two tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64645/text-between-two-tags/64747#64747)" which shows examples using `xslt`? `man xlst` doesn't work but I looked more into it and it seems to be some type of Perl script-thing? I found [this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365338), which is leading me to this conclusion.

Can someone please provide me with some guidance on how I can simply convert an XML file to CSV on OS X?

Comment: The tool that was suggested in the A'ers is XMLStarlet: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/. That's different than XSLT. XSLT files are XML stylesheet templates.

Comment: This blog post shows how to install XMLStarlet for OSX: http://blog.troyastle.com/2010/03/building-xmlstarlet-in-snow-leopard-osx.html

Comment: The comment doesn't explain how to use it, I have no idea what a xml template is, where to put it or how to use it.

Comment: Here's an example, hope this shows you how to install and use xmlstarlet.

Comment: Since there is no example XML document in the question, an answer would by necessity need to be extremely general, to the degree of being mostly unusable.

Answer (score 6):

The application XMLStarlet appears to be [available on OSX via `brew`](http://brewformulas.org/Xmlstarlet), so you should be able to install it like so:

```
$ brew install xmlstarlet
```

Once it's installed, you use it via the command line via the command `xmlstarlet`.

#### Usage

```
$ xmlstarlet 
XMLStarlet Toolkit: Command line utilities for XML
Usage: xmlstarlet [<options>] <command> [<cmd-options>]
where <command> is one of:
  ed    (or edit)      - Edit/Update XML document(s)
  sel   (or select)    - Select data or query XML document(s) (XPATH, etc)
  tr    (or transform) - Transform XML document(s) using XSLT
  val   (or validate)  - Validate XML document(s) (well-formed/DTD/XSD/RelaxNG)
  fo    (or format)    - Format XML document(s)
  el    (or elements)  - Display element structure of XML document
  c14n  (or canonic)   - XML canonicalization
  ls    (or list)      - List directory as XML
  esc   (or escape)    - Escape special XML characters
  unesc (or unescape)  - Unescape special XML characters
  pyx   (or xmln)      - Convert XML into PYX format (based on ESIS - ISO 8879)
  p2x   (or depyx)     - Convert PYX into XML
<options> are:
  -q or --quiet        - no error output
  --doc-namespace      - extract namespace bindings from input doc (default)
  --no-doc-namespace   - don't extract namespace bindings from input doc
  --version            - show version
  --help               - show help
Wherever file name mentioned in command help it is assumed
that URL can be used instead as well.

Type: xmlstarlet <command> --help <ENTER> for command help

XMLStarlet is a command line toolkit to query/edit/check/transform
XML documents (for more information see http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)
```

#### Example

Say you had this sample file, `sample.xml`.

```
$ cat sample.xml 
<root>
  <record id="1">
    <keyA>val_1A</keyA>
    <keyB>val_1B</keyB>
  </record>
  <record id="2">
    <keyA>val_2A</keyA>
    <keyB>val_2B</keyB>
  </record>
  <record id="3">
    <keyA>val_3A</keyA>
    <keyB>val_3B</keyB>
  </record>
</root>
```

To parse this file into CSV, for each record, (1, 2, 3), with each records corresponding values, (keyA, keyB), on a single line you could use the `concat` command like so:

```
$ xmlstarlet \
    sel -T -t -m /root/record \
    -v "concat(@id,',',keyA,',',keyB)" \
    -n sample.xml
```

Which would results in the following output:

```
1,val_1A,val_1B
2,val_2A,val_2B
3,val_3A,val_3B
```

The workhouse line in the above command is the `concat()` function. This is taking the elements from the XML record, `/root/record`.

#### References

- [Transforming an XML Document into a CSV using XMLStarlet](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/transforming-xml-document-into-csv-using-xmlstarlet/)
- [XmlStarlet Command Line XML Toolkit User's Guide](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)

Comment: This is not a robust CSV solution. It fails if the input data includes commas.