# awk, sed, grep, perl... which to print out in this case?

Tags: sed, grep, awk, regular-expression, perl

I have this syntax in a file (http response times from analog):

```
<thead><tr><th class="x">seconds</th><th class="R">reqs</th><th class="r">%reqs</th><th class="B">Gbytes</th><th class="b">%bytes</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td class="x">0</td><td class="R">10927</td><td class="r"> 0.47%</td><td class="B">0.01</td><td class="b"> 0.18%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="x">&lt;= 0.01</td><td class="R">1026471</td><td class="r">44.59%</td><td class="B">0.11</td><td class="b"> 1.81%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="x">0.01-0.02</td><td class="R">535390</td><td class="r">23.26%</td><td class="B">0.06</td><td class="b"> 0.95%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="x">0.02-0.05</td><td class="R">93298</td><td class="r"> 4.05%</td><td class="B">0.27</td><td class="b"> 4.29%</td></tr>
```

etc.

What I want to be left with is the value for seconds - so 2 characters after "x" and before the first <

And also the request length, so 2 characters after "R" and before the next subsequent <

Probably not the best exercise to get to grips with regex but that's what I'm stuck with. Any help would be incredibly useful.

Expected result:

```
seconds reqs 
0 10927 
&lt= 0.01 1026471 
0.01-0.02 535390 
0.02-0.05 93298
```

Comment: The implementation of your theory: `sed 's/.*"x".\([^<]*\).*"R".\([^<]*\).*/\1\t\2/' file` Note that I posted this for your education only. Better do not use such solution.

Comment: I feel that this may be relevant here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags ;). No but seriously, if you need to parse HTML you might want to look at html parsers.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are very certain about the format of the HTML, you have
control over it, it is not critical with errors, etc. you could use
regex, - but as mentioned - not recommended.

I use it frequently myself, but then usually for one time extraction of
some simple data.

---

You could use e.g. Perl with [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/HTML-TokeParser-Simple-3.15/lib/HTML/TokeParser/Simple.pm).

Very simplified:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use HTML::Entities;
use utf8;

die "$0 [file | url]\n" unless defined $ARGV[0];

my $tp;
if ($ARGV[0] =~ /^http:\/\//) {
    $tp = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(url => $ARGV[0]);
} else {
    $tp = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(file => $ARGV[0]);
}

if (!$tp) {
    die "No HTML file found.\n";
}

# Array to store data.
my @val;
# Index
my $i = 0;

# A bit mixed code with some redundancy. 
# Could be done much simpler, - or much more safe. 
# E.g. Check for thead, tbody etc and call a sub to parse those.
# You could off course also print directly (not save to array),
# but you might want to use the data for something?
while (my $token = $tp->get_token) {
    if ($token->is_start_tag('th') && $token->get_attr('class') eq 'x') {
        $val[$i++] = $tp->get_token->as_is;
    } elsif ($token->is_start_tag('th') && $token->get_attr('class') eq 'R') {
        $val[$i++] = $tp->get_token->as_is;
    } elsif ($token->is_start_tag('td') && (
            ($token->get_attr('class') eq 'x') ||
            ($token->get_attr('class') eq 'R'))) {
        $val[$i++] = decode_entities($tp->get_token->as_is);
    }
}

my @width_col = (10, 8);

if ($i > 2 && !($i % 2)) {
    $i = 0;
    printf("%*s %*s\n",
        $width_col[0], "$val[$i++]",
        $width_col[1], "$val[$i++]"
    );
    while ($i < $#val) {
        printf("%*s %*d\n",
            $width_col[0], "$val[$i++]",
            $width_col[1], "$val[$i++]"
        );
    }
} else {
    die "ERR. Unable to extract data.\n"
}
```

Sample result:

```
$ ./extract htmlsample 
   seconds     reqs
         0    10927
   <= 0.01  1026471
 0.01-0.02   535390
 0.02-0.05    93298
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned [regex is not good for parsing html](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69039/awk-sed-grep-perl-which-to-print-out-in-this-case/69047#comment100065_69039). Similar to another [parse answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64708/8677) you can make a Ruby one-liner such as the following to do it for you. Note that it requires [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) which you can install as a gem (`sudo gem install nokogiri`).

```ruby
ruby -rnokogiri -e 'h = Nokogiri::HTML(readlines.join); h.css("tr .x").zip(h.css("tr .R")).each { |d| puts "#{d[0].content} #{d[1].content}" }' sample.html
```

It reads from sample.html and makes a two dimensional array that contains everything with the attribute `class="x"` inside a `tr` element paired with everything with the attribute `class="R"` inside a `tr` element. Then it prints one such pair per line. For your example the output is the following:

```
seconds reqs
0 10927
<= 0.01 1026471
0.01-0.02 535390
0.02-0.05 93298
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses `sed` and then you can use `cut` to get the fields you want.  This is a one-liner, but I wrote as a script file with comments for clarity.

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s!</*thead!<tbody!g;      # to not get caught by 'th' below
s!<t[dh][^>]*>!%%%!g;     # replace start tag 'td' or 'th' with a delimitor
s!</t[dh]>!@@@!g;         # replace end tag 'td' or 'th' with a delimitor
s/<[^>]*>//g;             # delete any other tags
s/%%%\([^@]*\)@@@/\1 /g;  # get text between start and stop delimitors with a space
s/ $//                    # remove trailing space
```

Calling this as:

```
$ sed -f glean.sed test.html
seconds reqs %reqs Gbytes %bytes
0 10927  0.47% 0.01  0.18%
&lt;= 0.01 1026471 44.59% 0.11  1.81%
0.01-0.02 535390 23.26% 0.06  0.95%
0.02-0.05 93298  4.05% 0.27  4.29%
```

Then you can use what you like to get the first two fields (as I suggest with `cut`).