# Trying to remove all ids from an HTML file with grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, html

I'm trying to remove all `id=" "`s from an `.html` file but I'm not sure where I am going wrong.  I tried using regular expressions but all I am getting is the `.html` file rendering in my Ubuntu terminal.

Code:

```
grep -Ev '^$id\="[a-zA-Z][0-9]"' *.html
```

I am executing it with `bash ex.sh`.

Comment: Parsing/modifying HTML is not to be done with regular expressions.

Comment: better alternative? awk or sed?

Comment: Is this HTML(i.e. SGML) or XHTML ?

Comment: just simple `.html`.  Its been awhile but something like `awk '// || // *.html > *.html` comes to mind.

Comment: Why the "^$" at the beginning?  That means an empty line...  Are all your id=-statements after an empty line?  If the id=-statements are on separate lines - without anything else - you may use grep to remove them, but if they're inside a line, that won't work.  You can *match* just the part of a line matching your expression, but you can't "un-match" it.  I think you'll have more luck using 'sed'.

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/339378)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though this goes against my better judgment I'll post it (`sed` part).

That is: if it is for a quick and dirty fix go ahead. If it is a bit more
serious or something you are going to do frequently etc. Use something else
like python, perl etc. where you do not rely on regular expressions, but rather modules to handle HTML documents.

One of the simpler ways would be to use e.g. sed.

```
sed 's/\(<[^>]*\) \+id="[^"]*"\([^>]*>\)/\1\2/' sample.html > noid.html
```

Explained:

```
            +--------------------------------- Match group 1
            |                      +---------- Match group 2
         ___|___                ___|___
        |       |              |       |  
sed 's/\(<[^>]*\) \+id="[^"]*"\([^>]*>\)/\1\2/' sample.html > noid.html
     |   |  | |   |  |    | ||    |  |      |
     |   |  | |   |  |    | ||    |  |      +- \1\2  Subst. with group 1 and 2
     |   |  | |   |  |    | ||    |  +-------- >     Closing bracket
     |   |  | |   |  |    | ||    +----------- [^>]* Same as below
     |   |  | |   |  |    | |+---------------- "     Followed by "
     |   |  | |   |  |    | +----------------- *     Zero or more times
     |   |  | |   |  |    +------------------- [^"]  Not double-quote
     |   |  | |   |  +------------------------ id="  Literal string
     |   |  | |   +---------------------------  \+   Space 1 or more times
     |   |  | +------------------------------- *     Zero or more times 
     |   |  +--------------------------------- [^>]  Not closing bracket
     |   +------------------------------------ <     Opening bracket
     +---------------------------------------- s     Substitute
```

Use `sed -i` to edit file in place. (Regrets possible but no undo.)

---

Better; example using perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use HTML::Entities;
use utf8;

die "$0 [file]\n" unless defined $ARGV[0];

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(file => $ARGV[0]);

if (!$parser) {
    die "No HTML file found.\n";
}

while (my $token = $parser->get_token) {
    $token->delete_attr('id');
    print $token->as_is;
}
```

---

Your grep command would match nothing. But as you use the invert option `-v` it
prints everything not matching – thus the entire file.

grep is not a *in place file modifier* but normally a tool for finding stuff
in file(s). Try e.g.:

```
grep -o '\(<[^>]*\)id="[^"]*"[^>]*>' sample.html
```

`-o` means print only matching pattern. (Not whole line)

`sed`, `awk` etc. are often used to edit streams or files. E.g. as by example above.

---

From your grep there is a few miss-conceptions:

```
 id\="[a-zA-Z][0-9]"
```

Would match exactly:

1. `id=`
2. **One** character in the range `a-z` or `A-Z`
3. Followed by **one** single digit

In other words it would match:

```
id="a0"
id="a1"
id="a2"
...
id="Z9"
```

Nothing like: `id="foo99"` or `id="blah-gah"`.

---

Further it would match:

```
 ^ <-- start of line (As it is first in pattern or group)
 $ <-- end of line   (As you use the `-E` option)
 # Else it would be:
 ^ <-- start of line (As it is first in pattern or group)
 $ <-- dollar sign   (Does not mean end of line unless it is at end of
                      pattern or group)
```

Thus nothing.

Comment: man that's awesome!

Comment: minor note: the sed example will only transform the first match on a line, add a `/g` on the end to transform all tags found in a single input line. If you have mixed case tags, add an `i` in there as well to be case-insensitive. (`s/.../.../ig`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seriously suggesting this, but I worked out how to do it with an XSLT processor that accepts html.  Run with `xsltproc --html strip-html-id.xslt input.html`

```
<!-- strip-html-id.xslt -->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@id" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64708/8677) you can use a Ruby one-liner to parse HTML. For example, you can use the following:

```ruby
ruby -rnokogiri -e 'doc = Nokogiri::HTML(readlines.join); doc.xpath("//@id").remove; puts doc' sample.html
```

This line parses the file given as argument, sample.html, strips it of all `id` attributes and prints the output. If sample.html is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h2 id="section1">Section 1</h2>
    <h2 id="section2">Section 3</h2>
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <h2 id="section5">Section 5</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

it outputs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <h2>Section 5</h2>
  </body></html>
```

Note that by using `Nokogiri::HTML()` will put the content inside `html` and `body` if it is not already in such a structure and it will also add a `DOCTYPE`. If you want to strip `html`, `body` and `DOCTYPE` or do not want them added you can use

```ruby
ruby -rnokogiri -e 'doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(readlines.join); doc.search("@id").remove; puts doc' sample.html
```

which for the same input file will output

```html
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <h2>Section 5</h2>
```

Comment: Is there a bug in that? It strips of `DOCTYPE`, `head` etc. and put it all in `body` tag. It also reformats document.

Comment: @Sukminder I made an edit shortly after I posted. Now it does not wrap it in anything.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, but it is with your current line. Spec: `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]`, `Nokogiri (1.5.5)`. Ran it on the HTML for this site. (As in this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72917/trying-to-remove-all-ids-from-an-html-file-with-grep/72938)

Comment: @Sukminder I have edited to show the difference of `parse` and `fragment`.

Comment: No. If the `<body>` tags are in column 1 (no space before it on the line) – it is not stripped using `fragment`. If there is a space or a tab etc. in front of it then it is. It also moves such things as meta, title, link to css and javascript down to body when not stripped. [Here is a sample.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=v9Jp2Ng4)

Comment: @Sukminder I am quite new to Nokogiri so I cannot explain its behaviour. Maybe you should use the resources listed in http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/getting_help.html and report back?